# Variable results do not match cout

Tags: c++, c-strings

So I am fairly new to C++ and I have this class assignment. Normally I would ask my professor for help, but he does not answer e-mail for students and our class is once a week. I have tried to make this work for days with weird results, so here is the problem.

Here is the prompt:

> Sort a single column array and/or sort a 2 dimensional array 
>   of characters given any column.  Here is what I used as my
>   template specification.

Here is the class he gave use to use (we cannot change this):

```
//This class sorts arrays either ascending or descending
template<class T>
class Prob2Sort
{
private:
    int *index;  //Index that is utilized in     the sort
public:
    Prob2Sort(){index=NULL;}; //Constructor
    ~Prob2Sort(){delete []index;};  //Destructor
    T * sortArray(const T*,int,bool); //Sorts a single column array
    T * sortArray(const T*,int,int,int,bool); //Sorts a 2 dimensional array
};
```

and here is the driver program (also can't touch it):

```
cout<<"The start of Problem 2, the sorting problem"<<endl;
Prob2Sort<char> rc;
bool ascending=true;
ifstream infile;
infile.open("Problem2.txt",ios::in);
char *ch2=new char[10*16];
char *ch2p=ch2;
while(infile.get(*ch2)){cout<<*ch2;ch2++;}
infile.close();
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Sorting on which column"<<endl;
int column;
cin>>column;
char *zc=rc.sortArray(ch2p,10,16,column,ascending);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<16;j++)
    {
        cout<<zc[i*16+j];
    }
}
delete []zc;
cout<<endl;
```

And output:

```
The output from this problem.

The start of Problem 2, the sorting problem
    Lcekoeddhoffbmg
    Lkcmggjcdhhglif
    Cgldjhcekjigcdd
    Cgldjhcekjigcdn
    Bffmdbkcenlafjk
    Fggdijijegfblln
    Jjlncnimjldfedj
    Amliglfohajcdmm
    Balgfcaelhfkgeb
    Kmlhmhcddfoeilc

Sorting on column 15
    Cgldjhcekjigcdn
    Fggdijijegfblln
    Amliglfohajcdmm
    Bffmdbkcenlafjk
    Jjlncnimjldfedj
    Lcekoeddhoffbmg
    Lkcmggjcdhhglif
    Cgldjhcekjigcdd
    Kmlhmhcddfoeilc
    Balgfcaelhfkgeb
```

Now I did change few things just to get it working; here is my crazy code in main.cpp:

```
cout<<"The start of Problem 2, the sorting problem"<<endl;
Prob2Sort<char> rc;
bool ascending=true;
ifstream infile;
infile.open("Problem2.txt",ios::in);
char *ch2=new char[(4*17)+ 1];
char *ch2p=ch2;
while(infile.get(*ch2)){ch2++;}

infile.close();
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Sorting on which column"<<endl;
int column;
cin>>column;
char *zc=rc.sortArray(ch2p,4,17,column,ascending);
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
        for(int j=0;j<17;j++)
        {
                cout<<zc[i*17+j];
        }
}
delete []zc;
cout<<endl;
```

Now here is my class:

```
template<class T>
T* Prob2Sort<T>::sortArray(const T* arry, int rows, int cols, int column, bool order)
{
    // put into new array to sort and return
    T* a_ray = new T[(rows*cols) + 1];

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
               a_ray[i*cols+j] = arry[i*cols+j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
               cout << a_ray[i*cols+j] ; // displays fine
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    T temp;
    bool test = true;

    do
    {
        test = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++)
        {
            cout << "Row " << i << endl;
            if(a_ray[i*cols+column] > a_ray[(i+1)*cols+column])
            {
                cout << "ELEMENT 1 IS " << a_ray[i*cols+column] << endl;
                temp = arry[i*cols+column];
                cout << "TEMP IS " << temp << endl;
                a_ray[i*cols+column] = a_ray[(i+1)*cols+column];
                cout << "ELEMENT 1 NEW is  " << a_ray[(i)*cols+column] << endl;
                cout << "ELEMENT 2 is " << a_ray[(i+1)*cols+column] << endl;
                a_ray[(i+1)*cols+column] = temp;
                cout << "ELEMENT 2 NEW is  " << a_ray[(i+1)*cols+column] << endl;
                test = true;
             } 

        }      
    }while(test);
```

Now the problem is (and  I had this before I touched everything) was... not sure how to explain it, but I added those couts to view the problem so I will post the output
I choose row 0 to sort so the way I have it only sorts that one character in each element so I haven't attempted to do what my professor wants just yet

```
 // this is the file read in (i also has 2 elements at end of each line for the newline 
 //characters which I can see in a hex editor) 

abcdefghijklmno
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
1234567890pqrst
uvwxyzPQRSTUVWX
Row 0
ELEMENT 1 IS a
TEMP IS a
ELEMENT 1 NEW is  A
ELEMENT 2 is A
ELEMENT 2 NEW is  a
Row 1

// **PORBLEM HERE***


ELEMENT 1 IS a
TEMP IS A

//**the two couts above should be the same... as you can see why here,

   cout << "ELEMENT 1 IS " << a_ray[i*cols+column] << endl;
   temp = arry[i*cols+column];
   cout << "TEMP IS " << temp << endl;

//////////////////////////////// should be same value!!!! but it is not
// t only does this every other loop if I remember right. it will not change the vlauebut retain the last one in it

ELEMENT 1 NEW is  1
ELEMENT 2 is 1

ELEMENT 2 NEW is  A
```

Thank you for anyone who helps, sorry for my mess but  I reallllly need this and I can't figure out what is going on and even my professor at some point when I was able to ask him, could not but we still have to turn it in, I just can't get this error fixed

Comment: That's a lot of stuff here, particularly code.  If you're encouraging us to use it, make it more organized.  If you believe it's an "eye test" situation, cut it down to the concise portion of code you believe is problematic.  I applaud the detail, just neaten it up a bit for us, based on the type of help you would like.

Comment: Well I won't lie, I still am not used to formatting code the way this site requires but I am not sure how much information you guys need. So  I posted what is suppose to happen and what is happening. But I will do what ever I can

Comment: I don't get why you are using `arry` and `a_ray` there, shouldn't that all be `a_ray`. Terrible variable naming by the way.

Comment: Hrmmm, shouldn't you change `temp = arry[i*cols+column];` to `temp = a_ray[i*cols+column];`?

Comment: @Tanner: in general if you provide code, you should either: A: supply everything bundled nicely in a way that allows us to run it ourselves, with a compilation command.  or B: supply the point at which you suspect something goes wrong.  If we then decide this is fine, you can add bits, but at least get the discussion going on something as concise as possible.

Comment: Damn, you are right sir!  I feel like an idiot right now! I did have a problem similiar to this before I redid it, so i guess forgetting to change that just created a similar problem I overlooked!! thank you, ill get back to you guys if anything!

Comment: @ChrisCM ok thank you, next time I will provide a better format sorry for any in convince and thank you for your input

Comment: The example code from the assignment is showing some really bad C++ habits. You might want to ask your professor when you get a chance why he choose to use raw pointers and manual `new` and `delete` and not `std::string`. The code shown isn't safe in more ways than one.

Comment: Although I agree with mvds that the variable naming is not ideal, it would have been helpful to give you an idea of how to do that better. Look for C++ Best Practices on the web and/or on here to get some ideas about how to write good, readable code.